# Why does my program not print anything for very large numbers(within the long range)?

Tags: java

I wrote a program to determine the largest prime factor of an input. It works fine except with very large numbers. I tried it with "600000000000" and it does not print anything, but it doesn't terminate the program or print an error. This number is within the range of a long, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    long num =  s.nextLong();
    //terminated by 0
    while(num!=0L){
        System.out.println(largestPrimeFactor(num));
        num = s.nextLong();
    }

}
public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
    //check if n is a multiple of 2
    if (n!=2L && n%2L==0L) return false;
    //if not, then just check the odds
    for(long i=3L;i*i<=n;i+=2L) {
        if(n%i==0L)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public static long largestPrimeFactor(long x){
    long max=0L;
    if(x%2L==0L){
        max=2L;
    }
    for(long i = 3L; i<=x; i+=2L){
        if(x%i==0L && isPrime(i)==true){
            max=i;
        } 
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: You should tag this with the appropriate language (I.e: C / C++, Java) so ppl know what language constraints they have to infer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things.

First of all factoring into prime numbers is computationally expensive, which is why it is used as part of the basis for encryption systems !

Secondly your algorithm is really the slowest possible.  There are *much* better algorithms for this.  For example try [Pollard Rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm).  Algorithm choice is very important here.

Finally Java has a BigInteger class and one thing it has is a very fast test to see if something is prime or not ( isProbablePrime() ).  This test is probabilistic, in that it checks with a very high probability that something is a prime, but cannot absolutely guarantee it.  It's pretty close to certain, but not quite.

BigInteger is for huge numbers ( thousands of bits or more ), but if you want to play with prime factorization it is a good tool for Java.

Answer (score 4):

Your program doesn't print output because it is still processing. Finding the prime factors of a large number can take a very long time.